# PHP Array adding to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function that creates arrays and then I want to add to a main master array that I can then json_encode...

So the code

```
$pathtocsvs = "/var/www/csvfiless/";
$mainarray= array();

$filearray = getDirectoryList($pathtocsvs);
sort($filearray);

foreach ($filearray as $v) {
    parseCSV($pathtocsvs. $v);;   
}

print_r(json_encode($mainarray)); //outputs nothing but an empty [] json string
```

And the parseCSV function, I have removed some of the irrelavent code.

```
function parseCSV($file){

$file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
$output = "";

$locations = array(); 

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

    $lat = $line_of_text[0];
    $lon = $line_of_text[1];
    $output =  $lat.",". $lon ;

    array_push($locations,$output);

}

array_push($mainarray,$locations);   //line 47 that is the error
print_r($locations);  //This does display the array
print_r($mainarray);  //This displays nothing

fclose($file_handle);

}
```

And this error appears in the log...

```
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/test.php on line 47
```

Comment: array_push($mainarray,$locations);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix parseCSV function: replace

```
$output = "";
```

to

```
$output = array();
```

and after

```
fclose($file_handle);
```

add

```
return $output;
```

Then change the block in code like this:

```
foreach ($filearray as $v) {
    $mainarray[] = parseCSV($pathtocsvs. $v);
}
```

Comment: Actually, just returned, $locations and then you other code.  Works well!

Answer (score 0):

2 problems that I can see... you've declared `$mainarray` outside the function, so to access it, you'll need to use `globals`. Secondly, to concat two arrays, you need to use `array_merge`.

```
function parseCSV($file){
    globals $mainarray;
    $file_handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $output = "";

    $locations = array(); 

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
        $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);

        $lat = $line_of_text[0];
        $lon = $line_of_text[1];
        $output =  $lat.",". $lon ;

        array_push($locations,$output);

    }

    $mainarray = array_merge($mainarray,$locations);
    print_r($locations);  //This does display the array
    print_r($mainarray);  //This displays nothing

    fclose($file_handle);
}
```